# Get Time difference between group of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following structure

```
ID         ActivityTime             Status
19        2013-08-23 14:52            1
19        2013-08-23 14:50            1
19        2013-08-23 14:45            2
19        2013-08-23 14:35            2
19        2013-08-23 14:32            1
19        2013-08-23 14:30            1
19        2013-08-23 14:25            2
19        2013-08-23 14:22            2
53        2013-08-23 14:59            1
53        2013-08-23 14:56            1
53        2013-08-23 14:57            1
53        2013-08-23 14:52            2
53        2013-08-23 14:50            2
53        2013-08-23 14:49            2
53        2013-08-23 14:18            2
53        2013-08-23 14:30            1
```

I want to calculate the total time difference for each ID against Status 2. For example ID 19 stayed on Status 2 from 14:35 To 14:50 (15 minutes), then 14:22 to 14:30 (8 minutes). So the total ID 19 stayed on Status 2 is 23 minutes. **(In both cases I considered the minimum time for status 2 to status 1)**
 **The problem is**  how do I only include difference between Status where they are different in **next row**.

For example I would exclude the first record in the table with the status 1 and pick the second row. Same is the case with Status 2. I would pick the minimum time, calculate their difference and then add them up for multiple groups of status against each channel.

I have tried using CURSOR but can't seem to make it work. I am also pretty confident that I can achieve that in C# after getting all the data and then looping through it. But I am just wondering if there is a direct way of getting the information without a loop. I also created a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07830/8)  with data, but I can't seem to make it work. I am coming from C# background with basic knowledge of SQL. Would be glad if someone can help me out.

Comment: `14:35 To 14:50 (5 minutes)`? 5 minutes or 15 minutes? You should review the rule in your question and make sure it is what you want because it's very important for the answers being able to help you.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to do.. could you maybe elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @KingKing, that was a typo, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @NewHire now you have 15 min + 5 min = 30 min.

Comment: @Botis, I want to get the time difference an ID stayed on `status = 2`.

Comment: Can you change your database design? Currently you are recording snapshots at random intervals - you'd be far better off recording status changes only.

Comment: @Botis, I am messing it up, but I think its fixed now, it should be 23 minutes, as I took the minimum time from Status 2 to Status 1. just modified my answer

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst, actually I can't. There is more information to that, I need to log each status change and its time, but just want to calculate the total time an ID stayed on Status 2

Comment: You might want the [LAG](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/) function, bu that's only available in SQL Server 2012.  For example: `SELECT ID, ActivityTime, Status, LAG(ActivityTime, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY ActivityTime) as ActivityTimePrev
, LAG(Status, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY ActivityTime) as StatusPrev
FROM Log`.  [Here's an article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/) about simulating it in 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CTE ([common table expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) can be used like a specialized temp table.  It allows you to (in this case) dynamically create a row number that you can later create a self join on.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
--create temp table
select 19 as id,'2013-08-23 14:52' as activitytime,1 as status
into #temp
union all
select 19,'2013-08-23 14:50',1 union all
select 19,'2013-08-23 14:45',2 union all
select 19,'2013-08-23 14:35',2 union all
select 19,'2013-08-23 14:32',1 union all
select 19,'2013-08-23 14:30',1 union all
select 19,'2013-08-23 14:25',2 union all
select 19,'2013-08-23 14:22',2 union all
select 53,'2013-08-23 14:59',1 union all
select 53,'2013-08-23 14:56',1 union all
select 53,'2013-08-23 14:57',1 union all
select 53,'2013-08-23 14:52',2 union all
select 53,'2013-08-23 14:50',2 union all
select 53,'2013-08-23 14:49',2 union all
select 53,'2013-08-23 14:18',2 union all
select 53,'2013-08-23 14:30',1

--build cte table
;WITH cte
AS (
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  id, activitytime) AS RowNum
FROM 
    #temp
)

--query cte table, self joining row 1 to row 2 to compare.
SELECT a.id, sum(DATEDIFF(minute,b.ActivityTIme,a.ActivityTime)) as TotalTime
FROM 
 cte AS A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN cte AS B   
 ON A.RowNum = B.RowNum + 1 and a.id = b.id
where b.status = 2
group by a.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks perfect, I wish I could upvote you multiple times.

Comment: Notice that I am ordering the first query by ID and activitytime.  This is how I am establishing the row order.  This needs to be established because you need to know what the "next" row is.  The second part of the query is the recursion that joins the current row to the next row

Comment: This query count a sum between all `ActivityTime` where `Status` = 2, but real sum must be between first row with `Status = 2` and next first appearing row with `Status = 1`

Comment: No, it counts up the activity time where status = 2 on the right hand table.  On the left hand table it includes the first status = 1, this allows you to take it into consideration when doing the datediff.  Using that sql try a select * on the bottom query and look at the time diffs.